# View.OnClickListener on inner class into Adapter is't work

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I have simple adapter with inner holder class.

I try to implement on item click listener this way, and it's not working:

```
class ThemeAdapter(private val callback: (position: Int) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ThemeAdapter.ThemeHolder>() {

    private lateinit var themeList: Array<String>

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return themeList.size
    }

    fun setThemes(themes: Array<String>) {
        themeList = themes
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ThemeHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
        return ThemeHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_library_themes, viewGroup, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ThemeHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(themeList[position])
    }

    inner class ThemeHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {
        private var theme: TextView = itemView.spinner_library_dropdown

        fun bind(themeName: String) {
            theme.text = themeName
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            Timber.e("OnClick!")
            callback.invoke(adapterPosition) 
        }
    }
}
```

Timber log nothing.

It's simple to fix:

```
fun bind(themeName: String) {
            theme.text = themeName
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                Timber.e("OnClick!")
                callback.invoke(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
```

And i understand why second code working, but can someone explain me, why my first code is't working? What the difference?

Answer (score 0):

try this:in your adapter class

```
lateinit var mClickHandler: MyAdapterOnClickHandler

interface MyAdapterOnClickHandler {
    fun onClick(view: View, position: Int)
}

fun setOnClickHandler(myAdapterOnClickHandler: MyAdapterOnCLickHandler){
    mClickHandler = myAdapterOnClickHandler
}
```

in your Viewholder:

```
init {
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
}

override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    mClickHandler.onClick(itemView, adapterPosition)
}
```

your activity or fragment need to implements MyAdapter.MyAdapterOnClickHandler
in your activity:

```
//in onCreate 
adapter = MyAdapter(this)
adapter.setOnClickListener(this)

// then override the onclick
override fun onCLick(view: View, position: Int) {
   Log.d(LOGTAG, "clicked! $position")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind your ViewHolder that implements View.OnClickListener to your ViewHolder.itemView

```
fun bind(themeName: String) {
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    theme.text = themeName
}
```

You've just implemented needed method from interface View.OnClickListener, but you don't use it anywhere (it is just unused method in your code snippet). Android doesn't know that it is View, cause it implements its interface.

Code that worked for you in Java will look like:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    Timber.e("OnClick!");
    callback.invoke(adapterPosition);
});
```

And other that doesn't work

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(null); // therefore it doesn't work for you
// cause your itemView doesn't have any listener
```